listOf(listOf(string)) in lazyLayout(lazyColumn) compose
Currently only the outer List triggers a recomposition. How to have recomposition triggered when a string in the inner List is changed/added as well?
private var data by mutableStateOf<List<List<StringObject>>>(
    // Initialize with some sample data (20 rows, 10 columns)
    List(20) { outerIndex ->
        List(10) { innerIndex ->
            val value = "Value ${outerIndex * 10 + innerIndex + 1}"
            val imageUrl = if (innerIndex % 2 == 0)
                "https://example.com/image${innerIndex + 1}.jpg"
            else
                null
            StringObject(value, imageUrl)
        } as List<StringObject>
    }
)

I tried replacing this
mutableStateOf<List<List<StringObject>>>

with this:
mutableStateOf<List<MutableList<StringObject>>>

But that makes the app crash due to concurrent modification. I'm new to Compose and honestly it sucks due to all this immutable and state stuff. New languages should manage this stuff themselves internally.
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
  at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:1029)
  at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:982)
  at com.example.composetablee.MainActivity.addColumn(MainActivity.kt:143)
  at com.example.composetablee.MainActivity.access$addColumn(MainActivity.kt:28)
  at com.example.composetablee.MainActivity$onCreate$1$1$1$1$1$1$1.invoke(MainActivity.kt:51)
  at com.example.composetablee.MainActivity$onCreate$1$1$1$1$1$1$1.invoke(MainActivity.kt:51)
  at androidx.compose.foundation.ClickableKt$clickable$4$gesture$1$1$2.invoke-k-4lQ0M(Clickable.kt:167)
  at androidx.compose.foundation.ClickableKt$clickable$4$gesture$1$1$2.invoke(Clickable.kt:156)
  at androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.TapGestureDetectorKt$detectTapAndPress$2$1.invokeSuspend(TapGestureDetector.kt:255)
  at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
  at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTaskKt.resume(DispatchedTask.kt:178)
  at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTaskKt.dispatch(DispatchedTask.kt:166)
  at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.dispatchResume(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:397)
  at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.resumeImpl(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:431)
  at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.resumeImpl$default(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:420)
  at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.resumeWith(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:328)
  at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.SuspendingPointerInputFilter$PointerEventHandlerCoroutine.offerPointerEvent(SuspendingPointerInputFilter.kt:566)
  at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.SuspendingPointerInputFilter.dispatchPointerEvent(SuspendingPointerInputFilter.kt:456)
  at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.SuspendingPointerInputFilter.onPointerEvent-H0pRuoY(SuspendingPointerInputFilter.kt:469)
  at androidx.compose.ui.node.BackwardsCompatNode.onPointerEvent-H0pRuoY(BackwardsCompatNode.kt:374)
  at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.Node.dispatchMainEventPass(HitPathTracker.kt:314)
  at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.Node.dispatchMainEventPass(HitPathTracker.kt:301)
  at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.Node.dispatchMainEventPass(HitPathTracker.kt:301)
  at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.NodeParent.dispatchMainEventPass(HitPathTracker.kt:183)
  at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.HitPathTracker.dispatchChanges(HitPathTracker.kt:102)
  at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.PointerInputEventProcessor.process-BIzXfog(PointerInputEventProcessor.kt:98)
  at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.sendMotionEvent-8iAsVTc(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:1361)
  at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.handleMotionEvent-8iAsVTc(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:1307)
  at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.dispatchTouchEvent(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:1246)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3324)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2998)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3324)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2998)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3324)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2998)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3324)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2998)
  at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:776)
  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1967)
  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:4522)
  at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:734)
  at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:16476)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:8490)

How to deal with an immutable List since it won't let me add stuff in it? Making a mutable copy seems resource costly especially if one have a big sized list of list data.
Update 1-
Here is the current addColumn function
private fun addColumn() {
    data.withIndex().forEach { (index, row) -> // Use data.withIndex().forEach
        data[index].plus(ExcelCell("")) // Directly modify data
    }
}

Recomposition is still not triggering ;(
Recompisition not taken effect in innerList

I properly formatted your question and removed what you asked about LazyColumn: That seems to be not directly connected to the first problem you described and should therefore be asked in a separate question.

If you want to create a List of Lists, you can use mutableStateListOf():
val parentList = mutableStateListOf<List<String>>(
    // pass List<String> instances in here
    listOf("A", "B"), listOf("M", "N"), listOf("X", "Y")
)

This will result in a structure like this:
[
    ["A", "B"],
    ["M", "N"],
    ["X", "Y"]
]

To add a new List to parentList, use
parentList.add(listOf("1", "2"))

/*
Output:
[
    ["A", "B"],
    ["M", "N"],
    ["X", "Y"],
    ["1", "2"]
]
*/

To add a new element to a List inside parentList, do
parentList[2] = parentList[2].plus("Z")

/*
Output:
[
    ["A", "B"],
    ["M", "N"],
    ["X", "Y", "Z"],
    ["1", "2"]
]
*/

By this approach, Jetpack Compose should properly be able to pick up the changes made to the parentList or any nested List.

You get the ConcurrentModificationException because you modify the MutableList while iterating over it. You can solve this by using an Iterator as shown in below code:
@Composable
fun MainComposable() {

    val data = mutableStateListOf<List<String>>(
        // pass List<String> instances in here
        listOf("A", "B"), listOf("M", "N"), listOf("X", "Y")
    )

    Button(
        onClick = { 
            // use Iterator instead of forEach
            val iterate = data.listIterator()
            while (iterate.hasNext()) {
                val currentList = iterate.next()
                iterate.set(currentList.plus(""))  // update nested List safely
            }
        }
    ) {
        Text(text = "ADD COLUMN")
    }
}

Also note that you should not store the data variable globally in your Activity. Instead, it should only be declared within a Composable.
Once you click the Button, it will add a new empty String to each nested list within data. Adjust accordingly to use ExcelCell instead.

Thank you for your kind reply. I applied what you suggested. Now the app dosent crash, however still recomposition is not happening for the inneList.

Carefully check my code. You need to call data[index] = data[index].plus(ExcelCell("")), not only data[index].plus(ExcelCell("")).

Okayy. [ you were  super quick!!] I was going to write a proper deatiled comment by deleting that(already deleted though)

I finished the editing. Please see the last section of my post, here I have an example how you would store the data variable in a Composable and modify it.

Thank you. Just  now i compiled and tried  the app with the suggrestd changes  you wrote. Instead of @MainComposable , i  wtote tgh codes inside setContent since all my primary codes are here. But still cant get ride of "ConcurrentModificationExecption". Anyway, i now  will try to have all these code in a seperate composable and call it from setContent to exactly imitate of what you wrote. Im marking the answer as correct in advanced! Appreciate help!!

I updated my answer once again. I wasn't aware that you could get aConcurrentModificationException  when modifying the MuableList while iterating over it. Please try the updated code and let me know if it finally works.

Okayy. On it.‎ ‎ ‎ ‎

Now It works. Really appreciate your efforts. https://imgur.com/a/AD34YW7
